# How to expand a lookupfield in a sharepoint document library using rest

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint(SP) library with some custom columns.
One of the columns contains a lookup field pointing to a SP list.

I need to retreive the documents in the list and all the custom fields including the fields from the lookup list (join).

There are some Q&A on stackoverflow regarding this topc, but they are about SP lists not SP document libraries.

This is what I have come up with until now (using javascript to perform a GET):

```
{
"url": "sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/myfilelibrary')
/files?$select=Name,LinkingUrl,TimeCreated,TimeLastModified,Title,ListItemAllFields
&$expand=ListItemAllFields/myListIdId"
}
```

This results into:

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "ListItemAllFields": {
            "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
            "Id": 1,
            "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={abababab-efff-4e69-94de-128ff7c14256}&action=interactivepreview",
            "ContentTypeId": "0x010100769480B9F5404447A43367BFC5B86AAB",
            "Title": null,
            "checkResponsible": null,
>>>>>>>>>>>>"myListIdId": 15, <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            "SharedWithUsersId": null,
            "SharedWithDetails": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "Created": "2016-07-25T06:04:56",
            "AuthorId": 9,
            "Modified": "2016-07-26T15:11:27",
            "EditorId": 11,
            "OData__CopySource": null,
            "CheckoutUserId": null,
            "OData__UIVersionString": "9.0",
            "GUID": "898770aa-da56-40ae-9db1-430bba2da9bd"
        },
        "LinkingUrl": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/myFileLibrary/Document.docx?d=w3028f42eefff4e6994de128ff7cd6e48",
        "Name": "Document.docx",
        "TimeCreated": "2016-07-25T13:04:56Z",
        "TimeLastModified": "2016-07-26T22:11:27Z",
        "Title": ""
    }
]
}
```

The field myListIdId is returned but not expanded.

```
$expand=ListItemAllFields/myListIdId
```

should do the trick, but clearly it does not.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://threewill.com/using-the-expand-odata-query-option-in-sharepoint-2013/), you specify the expanded field in the select parameter.

**Revised:**

"...$select=Name,LinkingUrl,TimeCreated,TimeLastModified,Title,ListItemAllFields/myListIdId
&$expand=ListItemAllFields"